# Visiting ANTLR tokens that are not referenced by parser rules

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm attempting to write a syntax highlighter for Java, in C#, based on [this ANTLR v4 grammar file](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4). To do this, I'm currently attempting to keep track of an `_index` field in my visitor that I add to every time I pass a node. Here's the code:

```
private class Visitor : JavaBaseVisitor<object>
{
    private readonly string _rawText;
    private readonly SpannableString _text;
    private readonly ISyntaxStyler _styler;

    private int _index;

    internal Visitor(string text, ISyntaxStyler styler)
    {
        _rawText = text;
        _text = new SpannableString(text);
        _styler = styler;
    }

    public override object VisitAnnotation([NotNull] JavaParser.AnnotationContext context)
    {
        Advance("@", SyntaxKind.Annotation);
        VisitAnnotationName(context.annotationName());
        this.VisitChildren(context, 2);
        return null;
    }

    public override object VisitPackageDeclaration([NotNull] JavaParser.PackageDeclarationContext context)
    {
        int index = 0;
        var child = context.GetChild(0);

        while (child is JavaParser.AnnotationContext)
        {
            Visit(child);
            child = context.GetChild(++index);
        }

        Advance("package", SyntaxKind.Keyword);
        this.VisitChildren(context, index + 1);
        return null;
    }

    public override object VisitTerminal(ITerminalNode node)
    {
        Advance(node.Symbol.Text, SyntaxKind.Identifier);
        return null;
    }

    internal SpannableString HighlightText()
    {
        Visit(CreateTree(_rawText));
        return _text;
    }

    private void Advance(int count, SyntaxKind kind)
    {
        var span = _styler.GetSpan(kind);
        _text.SetSpan(span, _index, _index + count, SpanTypes.InclusiveExclusive);
        _index += count;
    }

    private void Advance(string toSkip, SyntaxKind kind)
    {
        int count = toSkip.Length;
        Debug.Assert(string.Compare(_rawText, _index, toSkip, 0, count) == 0);
        Advance(count, kind);
    }

    private static JavaParser.CompilationUnitContext CreateTree(string text)
    {
        var inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(text);
        var lexer = new JavaLexer(inputStream);
        var tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        var parser = new JavaParser(tokenStream);
        return parser.compilationUnit();
    }
}
```

The methods to pay attention to are `Advance` and `VisitTerminal`. Essentially, I'm relying on the fact that every node eventually decomposes into terminals, so if a node isn't handled by another override (such as `@` in `VisitAnnotation`), each of its terminals will be in `VisitTerminal`. Each call to `VisitTerminal` adds to an index field, which I assume is in sync with both the AST and the raw text. That is, `_index` should represent both the index in the raw text and the index of the current token.

I recently ran into a problem with whitespace. The grammar's rules seem to [eat up whitespace silently](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4#L1007-L1008) without mentioning it in any parser rules. This causes whitespace tokens to not go through `VisitTerminal`, causing everything to get misaligned. For example, consider this Java code snippet:

```
package a.b.c.d ;
```

Up until after `package` is processed, the index of the current token is the same as the index in raw text. However, when `a` is processed, `_index` has not been incremented for the whitespace so it's 1 behind what it should be. When `;` is processed, it will be 2 behind what it should be. Then  will get the coloring of `a`, `a` will get the coloring of the next `.`, `d` will get the coloring of `;`, etc.

Is there a way to pick up on whitespace tokens in the visitor so that the index doesn't get messed up? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the grammar eats whitespace.  But the lexer doesn't.  I handle syntax highlighting -- and therefore explicit token handling -- including whitespace as shown below.  The main thing is to override the `Emit` method of the lexer.  That's part of the process I outline here.

1. A small class that lets me record the type, start, and stop lengths in the source of tokens.

   ```
   public class TokenExtent
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Start { get; set; }
       public int Length { get; set; }
       public TokenExtent(string name, int start, int stop)
       {
           Name = name;
           Start = start;
           Length = stop - start + 1;
       }
    }
   ```
2. A list of TokenExtents that I fill with every parse.

   ```
   public static List<TokenExtent> TokenExtents = new List<TokenExtent>();
   ```
3. **A custom lexer where I override the `Emit()` method to classify tokens, including WHITESPACE**

   ```
   public class BailLexer : LISBASICLexer
   {
       public BailLexer(ICharStream input) : base(input) { }
       public override IToken Emit()
       {
           IToken token = base.Emit();
           switch (token.Type)
           {
           case ID :
               {
               TokenExtent extent = new TokenExtent("ID", token.StartIndex, token.StopIndex);
               BasicEnvironment.TokenExtents.Add(extent);
               break;
               }

               case COMMENT :
               {
               TokenExtent extent = new TokenExtent("COMMENT", token.StartIndex, token.StopIndex);
               BasicEnvironment.TokenExtents.Add(extent);
               break;
               }
               case WS:
               {
               TokenExtent extent = new TokenExtent("WS", token.StartIndex, token.StopIndex);
               BasicEnvironment.TokenExtents.Add(extent);
               break;
               }
   ```
4. A `Higlight()` method in my form where I apply the styling:

   ```
   private void Highlight()
   {
       foreach (TokenExtent ext in BasicEnvironment.TokenExtents)
       {
           switch (ext.Name)
           {
               case "ID" :
               {
                   etCode2.Select(ext.Start, ext.Length);
                   etCode2.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                   break;
               }
               case "COMMENT" :
               {
                   etCode2.Select(ext.Start, ext.Length);
                   etCode2.SelectionColor = Color.DimGray;
                   break;
               }
               case "WS":
               {
                   etCode2.Select(ext.Start, ext.Length);
                   etCode2.SelectionBackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

I changed the background color of whitespace to make it more prominent, so here's what it looks like:
[image]

As you can see, if you get in there with the lexer, you can treat these whitespace tokens the same as any other token that's been named by a lexer rule.